# After mounting S3 bucket system date of the directory is shown as 1970

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, amazon-s3, system, s3fs

I'm mounting S3 bucket using s3fs command, after mount the directory shows the system date as 1970.

My google search could not lead to a fix, looking for a help.

S3 Command:

```
s3fs rsqatestbucket2 /storage/s3test -o passwd_file=/opt/data/restore/.mng -o use_path_request_style -o url=http://s3.amazonaws.com -o uid=`id -u mng`,gid=`id -g mng`,allow_other,mp_umask=007
```

output from 'ls -l' command:

```
 [root@localhost storage]# ls -l
 total 1
 drwxrwxrwx. 6 root        root       165 Jul 10 16:01 device
 drwxrwxrwx. 1 mng     mng              0 Jan  1  **1970** s3test
```

Comment: John, Thanks for your note, If S3 has to be accessed as a file storage, what is the right way or tool to be used instead of s3fs ?

Answer (score 0):

When issuing stat/HeadObject, s3fs will first try its `x-amz-meta-mtime` header and if that is not found, return the `Last-Modified` header.  If the server does not return a header s3fs will default to time = 0, or 1 Jan 1970.  Objects created with s3fs should have both headers although objects created with other tools will only have the second header.  It is unusual that your server does not have the latter -- could you try `aws s3api head-object --bucket $YOURBUCKET --key $YOURKEY` to see if they are populated?  If one of these values is present but s3fs does not display it, please try upgrading to the latest s3fs version 1.90.